# Writing a recursive block 'while'

Tags: recursion, variable-definitions

I tried to write a program according to the definition 
[image]
using operator [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html), but it returns zero for each `d` an `m`, here I attach the code, help me fix it, please :)

```
A[d_,m_]:=
 Which[
  2d+1>m, 
   0, 
  2d+1<=m, 
  (2d+1)*Binomial[2d,d]*
   Sum[
    A[j,m]*Binomial[j,2d+1]*(-1)^(j-1)/(j-d)*BernoulliB[2j-2d],
    {j, 2d+1, m}
    ], 
  d==m,
   (2m+1)*Binomial[2m,m]
  ]; 
A[0,2]
```

Comment: What's `j`? Also, please post code formatted as code.

Comment: `j` is variable in recursive sum, such that `m>=j>=2d+1` to have non-zero values, this formula discused at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297900/coefficients-in-the-sum-sum-k-0n-1-sum-j-0ma-j-mn-kjkj-n2m1/297916?noredirect=1#comment741339_297916

Comment: But `A[d_,m_]` doesn't explicitly depend on `j`, so how is one supposed to implement your condition `j<0`?

Comment: `=` isn't the same as `==`, but that doesn't seem to be your only problem.

Comment: Note that the conditions `2d+1>m` and `2d+1<=m` cover all possibilities, so your third case is unreachable code.

Comment: `d=m` in sence of $A_{m,m}=(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}$

Comment: Personally, I'd write this as three conditional definitions using `/;`. But your essential problem is that your terminal definition yields 0. Your recursive definition is a sum of products, but since the sum always bottoms out at 0, it's always 0.

Comment: `d=m` means "when you see `d`, replace it with `m`". `d==m` means "is d equal to m?".

Comment: Main Definition revised, first line should be ignored

Comment: Dear John, im a newbie in Mathematica, so, if you can revise or fix this code, do it in separated example in comment, thank you

Comment: I cannot fix it, since **by your definition**, it is zero, always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76129/discussion-between-kolosov-petro-and-john-doty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case in the `Which`, `2d+1>m` ,seems a default for when neither the second case `2d+1<=m` nor the third `d==m` apply. But for all positive `d`, the first is satisfied when `d==m`, and because it is first the `d==m` case never gets used. The recursion "bottoms out" on zero, and so the recursive sum of products here is always zero.

I like to do this kind of thing with conditional definitions, where an unconditional definition serves as a default:

```
A[d_, m_] := 0
```

*Mathematica*'s evaluator automatically gives a conditional definition priority over an unconditional definition, so these will be tried first:

```
A[d_, m_] := (2 d + 1)*Binomial[2 d, d]*
   Sum[A[j, m]*Binomial[j, 2 d + 1]*(-1)^(j - 1)/(j - d)*
   BernoulliB[2 j - 2 d], {j, 2 d + 1, m}] /; 2 d + 1 <= m
A[d_, m_] := (2 m + 1)*Binomial[2 m, m] /; d == m
```

The specific conditional definitions override the default `0`, so you get a result.

Comment: yes, correct, thank you